# Angularfire $firebaseArray extend dynamic count\sum

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, firebase, angularfire

Am trying to achieve a dynamic count of certain node if defined:

This works but its not dynamic, you have to call sum().

```
app.factory("ArrayWithSum", function($firebaseArray) {
  return $firebaseArray.$extend({
    sum: function() {
       var total = 0;
       var todayDate = new Date();
       var start = todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
       var end = todayDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);

        // the array data is located in this.$list
        angular.forEach(this.$list, function(rec) {
            if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa)){
                if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa.completed)) {
                    if (rec.qa.completed >= start && rec.qa.completed <= end){
                        total++;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        return total;
    }
  });
});
```

I tried $$update but can't access this_counter in array:

```
  app.factory("counter", function($firebaseArray) {
      return $firebaseArray.$extend({
        sum: function() {
            return this._counter;
        },
        $$updated: function(){

           var changed = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$updated.apply(this, arguments);

           var todayDate = new Date();
           var start = todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
           var end = todayDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);

           if( !this._counter ) { 
               this._counter = 0; 
           }

            // the array data is located in this.$list
            angular.forEach(this.$list, function(rec) {
                if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa)){
                    if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa.completed)) {
                        if (rec.qa.completed >= start && rec.qa.completed <= end){
                            this._counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
          return changed;
        }
      });
    });
```

Does anyone know how to make a dynamic variable that I can update and access?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with $firebaseObject. Obviously you can add a property _counter to an object not an array. Any way this works and a good way to get a dynamic count.

```
app.factory("counter", function($firebaseObject) {
  return $firebaseObject.$extend({
    $$updated: function(){

       var changed = $firebaseObject.prototype.$$updated.apply(this, arguments);

       if( !this._counter ) { this._counter = 0; }

       var total = 0;
       var todayDate = new Date();
       var start = todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
       var end = todayDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);

        // the array data is located in this.$list
        angular.forEach(this, function(rec) {
            if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa)){
                if (angular.isDefined(rec.qa.completed)) {
                    if (rec.qa.completed >= start && rec.qa.completed <= end){
                        total++;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

      this._counter = total;
      return changed;
    }
  });
});


vm.panels = new counter(panelsRef);

{{vm.panels._counter}}
```

Am having issues with watches not firing after a long duration on IE11. So thought I'd try this approach.